# How to effectively sort keys (ksort) for class object?

Tags: php

In PHP you can use `ksort()` to alphabetically sort the keys of an array *but not a class object*. Is there a method for sorting the keys of a *class object*? *This would be very helpful for **quicker local development debugging** as I know what I'm looking for when I output a class for quick reference.*

Comment: it makes no sense to sort a class object, unless it has array-like behavior and then usual array functions can do the job.

Comment: Step 1) determine the keys, i.e., the field names (for example, via reflection), step 2) sort the field names.

Comment: @localheinz ...how? I wouldn't ask the question if I knew a time efficient fashion to implement it. :-\

Comment: @John have a look at some other questions, you'd be amazed how many people ask questions without even trying anything. Anyhow we want to know you have tried something, post your attempt here

Comment: Class object has properties, not keys. With `Reflection` you can get names of properties (as array I suppose) and find what you need.

Comment: @u_mulder Ah, properties instead of keys. Thank you for the clarification. I'll post what I find in a bit. :-)

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: Also there's `property_exists` function to check if required property exists in your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone trying to help in the comments. Because I only occasionally need this for *debugging purposes for local testing* this is one of the few instances that a cheap (as opposed to affordable or expensive) answer is acceptable; I'm simply visually confirming whether or not a class property has a desired value. In this case I'm debugging and testing numerous time zones with and without daylight savings so speeding up the debugging process is important to save time. However if someone has an affordable (proper) approach to (and using the correct terminology) *sort an object's properties* alphabetically then I'll be glad to test and accept that answer instead.

```
$a = array();
foreach ($class_object as $k => $v)
{
 $a[$k] = $v;
}
ksort($a);
echo '<section><pre style="font-size: 22px;">';
$a = print_r($a,1);
echo htmlspecialchars($a).'</pre></section>';
```

Comment: What's the problem of just `var_dump($class_object->prop_name)`?

Comment: @u_mulder I also sometimes need to ensure multiple properties are set relative to each other. In example besides timezone offsets I also need to look and determine if daylight savings is in effect. When debugging why bother to spend time typing out a specific property name when I can effectively just `print_r()` the object? My definitions aren't unwieldy so this is easier, quicker and sometime I can return to for unrelated debugging purposes. I have often just done exactly what you've said in some circumstances though, debugging is a subjective process. :-)